# Android PopupWindow is hidden behind navigation buttons in Nexus 5

Tags: android, popupwindow, popupmenu, nexus-4, nexus-5

I have created a custom popup menu which is displaying fine on the S4 but the problem is that part of it gets hidden behind the navigation buttons on Nexus 5.

I have tried using the setSystemUiVisibility() but that doesn't help as the buttons reappear as soon as I touch the view.

I have tried looking for an answer but haven't had any luck.

Comment: Can you edit your post with an image link or drop it here in a comment? I'll edit it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of content in your PopupWindow likely exceeds the screen real estate. Consider using a ScrollView in your PopupWindow's inflated layout.

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for your response. The popup shows completely when a cell high above the navigation button is clicked. The only time its obstructed is when the cell is low and the menu gets hidden behind the navigation buttons, it only happens on Nexus 5. I wanted to show the image but I dont have the reputation to upload an image.